# What are the use cases of instaclustr platform and how different from Cloud providing Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was going through instaclustr Platform and its uses cases, but somehow it does not clear me.
Could someone explain what are use cases of using instaclustr? How it is different AWS?

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/cloud

Comment: Based on their website, it seems that they can deploy Open Source infrastructure on top of Cloud Providers (eg AWS, Azure). In some cases (eg PostgreSQL, OpenSearch, Redis) it will be something that those Cloud Providers also offer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the CPO at Instaclustr so can provide you with a summary from my point of view.

There are a lot of detailed differences but at a high level:

- Instaclustr's platform provide access to the open source software as released by the open source projects (some AWS offerings such as KeySpaces are pretty significant variants from the open source tech)
- Our SLAs and support include the functionality of the open source software (for several AWS products, SLAs and support exclude issues with the open source software)
- Our platform provides a consistent experience across cloud providers
- In general, we work to provide a higher quality support experience, assisting with application usage issues and working cooperatively with our customer. We have very fast support response SLAs (20 mins at most) across our offerings.